# TypeScript type for elements in a form with various properties?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I can't seem to find a proper TypeScript type for form elements, which may have `.form` `.labels` `.value` `.disabled` etc

I found a type for non-form elements that can participate in HTML forms [ElementInternals](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementInternals), but what about actual form elements??

Does anyone know if such a type exists? Chat GPT recommends this but I'd rather not allow-list just the ones I can think of..

`type FormElement = HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLButtonElement | HTMLOutputElement;`

I'm iterating a bunch of elements, some of which are form elements and some of which are not, and I don't know how to use typescript effectively in checking these properties. Without typescript I'd just check if `element.form` exists, but with typescript checking `element.form` is an error because `HTMLElement` does not have `.form`

I'm looking for a check like `element instanceof HTMLFormElements` so that TypeScript won't warn about those properties not existing on just `HTMLElement`

Comment: @Dai the `element.form` is a `<form>` nothing to do with CSS, for example go to google, click the `<textarea>` and console.log `$0.form`, it will log the form

Comment: Have you tried using `if ("form" in element)`?

Comment: I think that's the way to go @pink, I was asking GPT for other operators like instanceof, and yea, just asserting `'labels' in e` and like, `e.labels instanceof NodeList` seems to be ok

Comment: "I was asking GPT"  I suppose eventually this will be reasonable, but right now this is like "I was asking someone prone to outlandish hallucinations"

Comment: @jcalz haha I actually highly recommend it, the ideas, creativity, simplicity, and speed are great, especially working on code that's kinda cryptic to humans. anyways if you want good docs / 100% truth, I highly recommend kapeli dash on option+space